# Why am I seeing this error "./main.go:7:6: syntax error: unexpected mars, expecting ("?

Tags: go

Here is my program. I am trying to convert a person's age on mars. It looks everything is fine here but still I am getting this error

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
var age int
fmt.Scanln(&age)
func mars(age) int{
days := age*365
return days/687
}
mars_age := mars(age)
fmt.Println(mars_age)
}
```

Comment: move `mars(age)` function outside `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func mars(age int) int {
    days := age * 365
    return days / 687
}
func main() {
    var age int
    fmt.Scanln(&age)

    mars_age := mars(age)
    fmt.Println(mars_age)
}
```

- Named `func`'s must be at the same level (i e. `main`, `mars`)
- Function parameters must have types `age int`

> **NOTE** Go permits anonymous functions (aka lambdas) too. In that case, you could define `mars` in `main` and you could assign it to a variable e.g. `mars := func(age int) int { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Please see this post on how to use nested functions https://stackoverflow.com/a/42423998/2693654

You need to have something like:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var age int
    fmt.Scanln(&age)
    x:= func (age int) int {
        days := age*365
        return days/687
    }
    mars_age := x(age)
    fmt.Println(mars_age)
}
```

Comment: Which means I can define a variable inside a function but can't define a function?

Comment: You can define a function, but you have to assign it to a variable.

Comment: But that again throwing same error
```
func main() {
var age int
fmt.Scanln(&age)
var x int = func mars(age int){
days := age*365
return days/687
}
mars_age := x(age)
fmt.Println(mars_age)
}
```

Comment: This is because the variable is of type func not int. I mean: 
var x func(int) int
x = func (age int) int {
days := age*365
return days/687
}

Answer (score 0):

```
func main() {
   mars := func (param type) return_type {
       return .....
   }

   returnedValue := mars(bela bela bela)
}
```